# Ampere Constant Memory and Read-Only Cache

Tags: gpu, nvidia, gpu-constant-memory

I am trying to figure out the Ampere memory hierarchy. Details are fairly consistent down to the L1 / Shared Memory in the SM, but descriptions become confusing for notions of constant memory and the read-only cache.

In Pradeep Gupta's blog, https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-refresher-cuda-programming-model/, he provides the following architectural picture:

[image: Test]

The figure shows the notion of the Read-Only memory separate from the L1/Shared Memory, and in his text he states the following:

*"Read-only memory — Each SM has an instruction cache, constant memory, texture memory and RO cache, which is read-only to kernel code."*

For Ampere, is there still a constant memory, if so how big is it? Is it still 64KB, tailorable or other? I assume this is for data defined as `__const__` in the code. What other data is in the "RO cache" noted above? Also, I thought I read that texture memory had been collapsed into the L1/Shared Memory space, is this not true?

I appreciate any insight that can be provided.

Comment: The R/O cache often had two levels with different sizes in previous architectures. The 64KB limit was only for user code. According to the PTX documentation and the SASS opcode format there were several (around 10 IIRC) 64 KB pages, which could also be internally used for different purposes, e.g. to distribute the kernel function parameters or to load coefficients for built-in math functions.